# Not allowing a value to go below a certain point

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a table called `seats` with the follow columns `SeatID`, `RouteAndDate`, `Date`, `Route` and `Seats`. In a perl/html form I am taking values away from seats.

At the moment `seats` is set as an Int with a default value of 50 as this is how many seats are available from the start.

What I want is for it to stop allowing me to take away from the value `seats` when the value gets too or goes past 0. I was wondering if there was any option for this in phpMyAdmin to set a minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do it through phpMyAdmin because phpMyAdmin is an administrative interface to manage MySQL databases -- when you're not directly manipulating the data through phpMyAdmin, it has no control over what you're doing.

You could do this through some code in your Perl script, a stored procedure to do the insert for you, or a trigger. Personally, I prefer checking this sort of thing in the application code but I suppose there are merits to each method.

In the Perl application, I would query the database for the number of total seats and the number of seats available/used -- before even displaying seating options to the user (it's pointless to show something they can't have anyway). You have to be cautious to avoid concurrency issues when doing the insert, of course.